# Entity Framework: Multiple models - the current state of thinking?

Tags: entity-framework

Apologies as this isn't exactly a unique question. I was looking at using EF with multiple models - I wanted to use a base model for our shared application framework and specific models for each of our applications.

Every post I find seems to point back to [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx) on working with large models. Am I to assume that even though this was written back in 2008 that in EF 4.1 there is still no improved support for this? Is this still the way forward with multiple/split models?