# use entities across multiple context entity framework 4

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I have a strange requirement, and do not know how to solve it.

I have a context that holds all my main entities.
One of the entity is "customers".

Now i have an other application with they're entities in a separate context.
However that application should be able to access the customers from the main context.
I don't mind if there is no relation. I know the key of the customer and can access it manually.

I thought about something like this: (example is pseudo vb.net)

```
Imports MainModels

Namespace OtherApplication

Dim myMainContext as new MainModels.MainContext

Dim myAppContext as new AppContext

Dim myOrder as order = AppContext.Orders.Find(OrderIdent)

Dim myCustomer as customer = MainModels.MainContext.Customers.Find(myOrder.CustomerKey)
```

Is there a common way of solving those kind of requirements?
Reason for me to separate the two context is, that the MainContext is not going to change anymore, while the AppContext could be extended. There could even be a App2Context for some other application.

I have found following post:
Choosing the subset by exposing foreign keys
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/24/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-1.aspx

Found similar question:
[Entity Framework: Multiple models - the current state of thinking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899548/entity-framework-multiple-models-the-current-state-of-thinking)